# Controlling build options (tests, etc) in included libraries in a modern CMake fashion

Tags: c++, build, cmake

What would the best way to replace global variables and instead move towards using target properties to control things like building tests in included libraries from the main applications CMakeLists.txt file?

**Background**

We have a c++ application, A, that uses, amongst others, inhouse libraries: lib B and lib C, that are included as git submodules in A:s repository. All respositories (a, B and C) share a common structure internal structure with all of them using Gtest as a unit test framework. This leads to all projects having a "unit_tests" target as well as a "gtest" target.

As a consequence, when including lib B and lib C in A:s CMakeLists.txt using add_subfolder() there is a conflict, as CMake requires target names to be unique and there is a total of 3 "unit_tests" targets in these 3 repos. There are other test targets as well, but they are so far unique. Renaming the test targets to b_unit_tests and a_unit_test would cure this, but doesnt feel right, and we would also need to rename the gtest targets to a_gtest, b_gtest...

Currently we have solved it by having global CMake variables B_BUILD_TESTS, C_BUILD_TESTS that are set to false in A:s CMakeLists.txt and control the inclusison of test in B and Cs CMakeLists.txt files using add_submodule(unit_tests). This has not been a real problem as we don't want to build and run unit tests for lib B and C when building app A. Doing so would have been mostly a waste of time.

Having watched Daniel Pfeifers ccpnow talk and read other blog posts on using CMake in a declarative way, I've started rewriting our CMake system with modern CMake practices in mind. So now the use of setting a global flag for every included library feels like an anti pattern I would like to avoid. Ideally I feel that tests would be best controlled by setting a property on an included targets. Something like below.

```
add_subdirectory(B)
set_target_properties(B PROPERTIES BUILD_TESTS false)
target_link_libraries(A PRIVATE B)
```

Ideally this would still include bs test targets, only make them not depend on b:s main target. But this seems very difficult to do without renaming all of bs targets with a b_ prefix. Technically b_unit_tests is still a different target than b, though from the context of A you would think of it as being part of target B.

Unfortunately I can't get the above to work as is seems like CMake already has a set of pre-defined properties for targets and adding new one doesn't seem fully supported. There is define_property and set_property, but from what I can see you cant use them to define properties on targets.

Suggestion how to rewrite the CMakeLists.txt in a more modern way with clear separation and configuration without resorting to global variables are greatly appreciated.

It seems that for modern CMake, libraries should export their paths and sources and in the export process you can add a namespace. Though I don't really get if this should also apply to libraries that are included as submodules and built together with the application? Is this the route I should go with libs A and

Comment: Wow... that's a **lot** of text. Are you sure you couldn't shrink it a bit?

Comment: I wanted to give a comprehensive background to the issue, I don't think less that 1 page is too much, but I can try to shorten it if it puts you off.

Comment: Providing an abstract at the beginning with a clear and specific question would definitely enhance your chance to have answers. ;)

Comment: There is no common approach for having tests in multiple projects which are built together. We may help you with your approach - using custom target's properties. But in this case you need to provide **more info** (more code) about your **problem**. What you have currently - "Unfortunately I can't get the above to work as is seems like CMake already has a set of pre-defined properties for targets and adding new one doesn't seem fully supported. There is define_property and set_property, but from what I can see you cant use them to define properties on targets." - isn't very descriptive.

Comment: Maybe it's not possible for the tests to co-exist. In that case I'm fine with either renaming them or controlling the inclusion of them with a property.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just rename test targets so that they wouldn't conflict with each other? You can also rule them with single `BUILD_TESTS` variable and set it to `ON` or `OFF` by default depending on how a library is built - as a standalone project, or as part of other one.

Comment: That it a possible solution, though the naming conflict is the minor of the 2 issues here.
The global BUILD_TESTS variable is what I want to move away from and would like to have some way of having that as a local property/variable for every target. I want to enable tests for A, but not for B and C.